# Wrapper class pagination - Constructor not defined: <Constructor>(SObject

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, pagination

EDIT:

I have implemented the changes here based on the Daniel Ballinger now I'm not getting error but when I click on the Next button is not going to the next page i have around 25 rows.

here is my retrofit code:

in the visualforce page i have action in the form like this:

```
<apex:page action="{!init}" ....
```

Retrofit Products Method:

```
public List<ProductWrapper> Products 
     {
      get 
      {
                List<Product2> products2 = new List<Product2>(); 
                list<ProductWrapper> pws = new list<ProductWrapper>();                 
               for(Product2 p : (List<Product2>)this.con.getRecords()) {  

                  if(p.Asset_Line_items__r.isEmpty()){
                     pws.add(New ProductWrapper(p,New Asset_Line_Item__c(Quantity__c = 0));
                     continue;
                 }
                   for(asset_line_items__c b : p.asset_line_items__r) { 
                        //ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper(p,b);
                        ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper((Product2)p,b);
                        pws.add(pw);
                 }
           }    
           Products2 = pws;
           return Products2;
        }
        set;
    }
```

END

Here is wrapper class:

```
public class ProductWrapper {

    public Product2 product {get;set;}
    public asset_line_items__c ali {get;set;}    

    public ProductWrapper(Product2 p, asset_line_items__c ali) {
        product = p;
        this.ali = ali;
    }
}
```

this is how I load the data in wrapper class: and the error i'm getting:

```
> Constructor not defined: [ProductWrapper].<Constructor>(SObject,
> Asset_Line_Item__c)
```

Constructor:

```
 public void init() {
        this.con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(SOQL);
        this.con.setpageNumber(1);
        this.con.setPageSize(5);
    }
```

Loading data in wrapper:

```
list<ProductWrapper> pws = new list<ProductWrapper>();
for(sObject p : this.con.getRecords()) {  

  if(p.Asset_Line_items__r.isEmpty()){
      pws.add(New ProductWrapper(p,New Asset_Line_Item__c(Quantity__c = 0));
      continue;
  }
  for(asset_line_items__c b : p.asset_line_items__r) { 
     ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper(p,b);
     pws.add(pw);
}
```

Pagination code:

```
    public void first() {
         con.first();
     } 
     public void last() {
         con.last();
     } 
     public void previous() {
         con.previous();
     }

     public void next() {
         con.next();
     }


 public ApexPages.StandardSetController con;

    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return con.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return con.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }

    public Integer totalPageNumber {
        get {
            Decimal totalSize = this.con.getResultSize();
            Decimal pageSize = this.con.getPageSize();
            Decimal pages = totalSize/pageSize;
            return (Integer)pages.round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
        }
        set;
    }
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="pb">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="a">                     
          <apex:column headerValue="quantity" >                            
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.ali.qty}" required="true" />                    
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" headerValue="Name"/> 
          <apex:column value="{!a.ProductName}" headerValue="P Name"/> 
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock> 

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!products.size>0}" styleClass="center">
                <apex:commandButton value="|< First" action="{!first}" rerender="properties" rendered="{!HasPrevious}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previous}" rendered="{!HasPrevious}"  rerender="properties"/>
                Page {!pageNumber} of {!totalPageNumber}
                <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}" rendered="{!HasNext}"  rerender="properties"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Last>|" action="{!last}" rendered="{!HasNext}" rerender="properties" />
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: change 
for(sObject p : this.con.getRecords()) {
to 
for(asset_line_items__c p : (List<asset_line_items__c>)this.con.getRecords()) {

Comment: While wrapper definition you used
asset_line_items__c but while passing values you used Asset_Line_Item__c, because of this compiler is not able to find the right definition and it is saying constructor is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `sObject` records returned by the [StandartSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) to `Product2` records.

E.g.

```
ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper((Product2)p,b);
```

Alternatively, you could do the conversion on the `for` loop.

```
for(Product2 p : (List<Product2>)this.con.getRecords()) {  
    //...
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error now but when I click on the next button its not going to the next page, I have updated my question with detail, please have a look - thanks

Comment: @NickKahn Ideally you would close this question out as solved if the initial problem is resolved and then start a new question if you have encountered a new problem.

Comment: Fair enough, I have created the new question and I will accept this as answer. here is the question I have posted: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141031/pagination-next-does-not-take-to-the-next-page