# Pagination setPageSize inconsistence

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

I'm using the following code and everything working fine but one thing i have noticed is that, when the very first page loads it add extra row, meaning that, if I `setPageSize = 5` I expect to see 5 rows correct but I see 6 rows and when I click the next button I see 5 rows.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
    Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
    Public Integer size{get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetCtrl {
        get{
            if(standardSetCtrl == null){
                size = 5;
                string queryString = 'Select Name, Type, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry from Account order by Name';
                standardSetCtrl = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
                standardSetCtrl.setPageSize(size);
                noOfRecords = standardSetCtrl.getResultSize();
            }
            return standardSetCtrl;
        }set;
    }
```

I do not have anywhere in my code where I'm setting the `setPageSize` I have only in one place.

I have tried doing something like this:
`standardSetCtrl.setPageSize(5-1);` then it displays 5 rows correct but when I click on `next()` then it displays 4 rows.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this behavior on my dev org using your code. Is it possible for you to paste your VF code as well?

Comment: I am assuming you are getting `size` from VF picklist.. and when you write size =5 ; it is only when size from VF page is blank, so can you change that to `if(size==null) size = 5;`

Comment: I do not have size in vfp, will try your suggestion checking  null

Comment: If you donot have size in VF, any reason for that `Public Integer size{get;set;}` ?  
Also, I am guessing when first time, you load the page, you are retrieving complete list. By the way, after using `setpagesize`, where are you doing `getRecords()`

Comment: i added to for debugging purpose to see what i'm getting when the page loads in vfp so when the page loads very first time it shows correct size which is 5 but the pageBlockTable showing me 6 rows, i have removed the `Public Integer size{get;set;}` and hard coded the value `standardSetCtrl.setPageSize(5)` but still see 6 rows.

Comment: Change your return as `return standardSetCtrl.getRecords()` and give it a try.

Comment: after changing the return got this error `Error: Return value must be of type: ApexPages.StandardSetController `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... (Assuming the list of accounts u using on VF page is aList)

```
    public class aController {

        public List<Account> aList{get; set;}

        public aController () {
            aList = new List<Account>();
            aList = standardSetCtrl.getRecords();

        }
          Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
        Public Integer size{get;set;}
        public ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetCtrl {
            get{
                if(standardSetCtrl == null){
                    size = 5;
                    string queryString = 'Select Name from Account';
                    standardSetCtrl = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
                    standardSetCtrl.setPageSize(size);
                    noOfRecords = standardSetCtrl.getResultSize();
                }
                return standardSetCtrl;
            }set;


  }
}
```

Comment: i think i found the cause of it and if you go to this question (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141031/pagination-next-does-not-take-to-the-next-page) which i posted earlier you will get the background, so I'm using the wrapper class and i'm pretty sure that what is causing is that, the list index starts with 0 thats why i'm getting 6 rows?

Comment: so the question i would say `how do i make my list 1 based rather than 0 based`

Comment: Anything using an array or a list will likely start at 0. Modify your numbers to reflect the starting index. In this case, 5 would be 4, for a total of 6 and 5 records, respectfully.